# Errror on creating a linked server.....Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, oledb, linked-server, oledbexception

Please see screenshot attached below:I go into the object explorer below, expand the linked servers node and right click the linked server I need and click "Test Connection" and I get the same error as discussed in this thread.

I am trying to write to tables in an access database, and the access database is connected to as a linked server. The code to create the linked server is the following sql, which is embedded in the application is as follows....

However, I get the error: Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" for linked server Process Output and the access database

I am running Access 2010

Also, do I need to manually create the directory Process Output and the access database in the "Process Output"? I actually created these manually but that did not help....I also disabled the the User Account Control settings but that did not help.

Comment: I installed the AccessRuntime.exe (that must be the 32 bit version of access) and also see the version number information for both sql server and access - but installing the run time did not help....

Comment: the output is:   Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4000.0 (Intel X86)   Jun 28 2012 08:42:37   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Express Edition with Advanced Services on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (WOW64)